# Sqoop import from mysql to HDFS using --null-string and --as-avrodatafile

Tags: mysql, hadoop, sqoop, avro

I have imported data from mysql to HDFS using sqoop import options

```
--null-non-string '999' --null-string 'ssssssss' --as-avrodatafile
```

mysql Data:

```
+----+------+-------+
| id | name | tmpid |
+----+------+-------+
| 14 | n    |    14 |
| 15 | o    |  NULL |
| 16 | NULL |    16 |
| 17 | NULL |  NULL |
| 18 | p    |  NULL |
| 19 | NULL |  NULL |
| 20 | q    |    20 |
| 21 | NULL |    21 |
+----+------+-------+
```

I got the same as output.It didnot convert null values
When I have tried without avro file format, I got the required output

```
--null-non-string '999' --null-string 'ssssssss' 



14  n   14
15  o   999
16  ssssssss    16
17  ssssssss    999
18  p   999
19  ssssssss    999
20  q   20
21  ssssssss    21
```

How to use Sqoop null-non-string option with avro?